# R: Error transforming object of class lm into data frame when using tidy()

Tags: r, select, linear-regression, permutation, p-value

I am trying to convert my lm model into a data frame in order to select the features with p-values above 0.05.

```
# Creating data frame from model's output
# library(permutations)
tm <- tidy(ols_reg)

# visualise dataframe of the model
# (using non scientific notation of numbers)
options(scipen = 999)
tm

tm$term[tm$p.value < 0.05]
```

but I get the error:
**Error in as.word(x) : can only coerce numeric objects to word**

Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

*P.S.: I can't find the original source of code. Please edit the question if you do.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, `permutations::tidy` is for working with objects of class *word*. I suspect you are looking for `broom::tidy`?

```
library(broom)
ols_reg <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
tm <- broom::tidy(ols_reg)
tm$term[tm$p.value < 0.1]
# [1] "wt"
```

Packages you import with `library` are added to your search path.

```
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"           "package:permutations"
# [3] "package:broom"        "package:tidyr"
# ...
```

When two (or more) functions have the same name, R will use the object found closest to the start of the search path. Packages get attached at position two, then pushed down as you attach more packages. **broom** will be masked by **permutations** if it is attached first. The `::` operator allows you to specify the package namespace in which to find the function.

Comment: Oh I see! There seems to be some conflict with tidyverse. I am trying uninstall.packages("tidyverse") to uninstall it but it can't seem to find the function...

Comment: Managed to do it by using: detach("package:tidyverse", unload = TRUE). Now there's aother problem: Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Package ‘broom’ version 0.7.2 cannot be unloaded: Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘broom’ is imported by ‘modelr’ so cannot be unloaded

Comment: Restarting RStudio and importing broom again solved the problem. thanks!

Comment: @Joehat other way around; **permutations** masked **tidyverse** which imports **broom**.